# Is it possible to toggle classList of the form that also has addeventlistener on?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, dom

I don’t really have a code snippet, I just thought about it and tried this, but it didn’t work

```
const checkUserEmail = function (e) {
  const regex =
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!regex.test(inputEmail.value)) {
    this.classList.toggle(".error");
  } else {
    return (inputEmail.value = "");
  }
};

form.addEventListener("submit", checkUserEmail, false);
```

Comment: Make sure you're not really using the curly smart quotes in your actual code. E.g. `“`

Comment: And you do not cancel the form submission..... and you do not use "." in a class name with toggle

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Give me a sec I'll get my laptop and share the whole thing

Comment: Look at your developer console. Are there errors?

Comment: Developer console doesn't show any errors. I've tried to console log "error" and it worked, but it doesn't toggle class

Comment: Don't edit the question you've got answer to -- this makes it near impossible for people coming to read it to understand what is wrong (since what was wrong was edited). I've edited the question again and put back the original error, so the answer makes sense now. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 1):

Remove dot `.` in the class name:

```
form.classList.toggle("error")
```

This should work just fine.

Comment: Dude, I don't know how I managed to put it there. Thank you, that solved the issue